# Problem when export data from Power BI to Csv-file with Power Automate

Tags: powerbi, export-to-csv, powerbi-desktop, power-automate, power-bi-report-server

I have a problem that is giving me a headache.

In Power BI, I have a column containing text like:

"I had a bad day\nCan you help me?".

I need the '\n' to appear in the CSV because I require it to be there for another program.

However, when I export it using Power Automate from PBi Desktop, everything goes fine, and that mark comes right into the CSV file. But my problem is that when I do the same thing from PBi web service, that mark isn't there anymore.

Any ideas on what to do?

Here's my flow:

[image]

I have tried everything I know.